# Custom log file for specific packages in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have a java package with specialized operations. Specialized in the sense that they are rarely used and i don't want to have them be mixed with normal logging.

I know that adding `logging.file=myapplication.log` will redirect the logging to this file but is there a way to specify only logging from specific packages to another file? Like `logging.file.my.package=special.log` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with the logging configuration Spring Boot provides. However, you can fall back upon the configuration that the logging framework provides. By default, this is [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/), which can be configured to log to multiple logging files.

To do that, you need to add a **logback.xml** file to your classpath and configure multiple [appenders](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html). For example:

```xml
<appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log1.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log2.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

And now you can define a separate logger in case you want to log to a different file. Make sure to add the `additivity="false"` otherwise, the log message will still be printed in both log files:

```xml
<logger name="com.example.apps.special-package" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE2" />
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
</root>
```

In this case, all logs will be written to `log1.log` (`FILE1` appender), while logs from the package `com.example.apps.special-package` will be written to `log2.log` (`FILE2` appender).

Answer (score 3):

Spring uses Logback as default logger. According to the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) you can setup **logback.xml** yourself to add to the default logging mechanism your 'special' behavior:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <property name="SPECIAL_FILE_NAME" value="special"/>
    <appender name="SPECIAL_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-10.10thread] %-5level %30.30logger{29}:%-4line %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
        <file>logs/${SPECIAL_FILE_NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/${SPECIAL_FILE_NAME}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="logging.file.my.package" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SPECIAL_FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Here we use Spring default `FILE` and `CONSOLE` appenders to log app info as usual (except `logging.file.my.package`), and use `SPECIAL_FILE` appender to log info from this package to file `log/special.log`.