# How do I log every db change using Spring Boot in a file?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to log every database change to a file. And I need to show how data looked before and how data looked after. 
 
For example, if I change person`s name it would be ok if following line was appended to my log file: "*updated person table: field 'first_name' was changed from 'Alex' to 'George' (person_id = 4622)*". 
And if I insert new person: "*inserted to person table: 'person_id' = 4623; 'last_name' = 'Smith'; 'first_name' = 'John'; 'status' = 0*". 
I make changes to db with services that use interfaces that extend JpaRepository and theoretically I could add code to append log file to every method of every service. But that's a lot of code, such approach does not follow DRY principles and I believe there should be better solution I haven't found yet. What should I use to achieve this?
I use Spring Boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE and my database is MariaDB.
Log file can have any format, but, I guess, the best would be yaml.

Comment: I want it but save the data into table in data base instead of file . what can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JDBC logging with [log4jdbc](http://log4jdbc.brunorozendo.com/) - see my related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346996/5380322).

To get it working in Spring Boot app just add [log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter) to your project, when set jdbc logging props as following:

```
logging.level.resultsettable=info
logging.level.sqltiming=info
logging.level.sqlonly=fatal
logging.level.audit=fatal
logging.level.resultset=fatal
logging.level.connection=fatal
```

Then you get full SQL queries, their execution time and their results in the app log.

To make queries print in one line you can use these settings of log4jdbc:

```
log4jdbc.dump.sql.addsemicolon=true
log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=0
log4jdbc.trim.sql.extrablanklines=false
```

Then you get in your log something like this:

```
2018-08-27 14:36:14.183  INFO 5452 --- [127.0.0.1] jdbc.sqltiming       : SELECT 1; {executed in 1 msec}
2018-08-27 14:36:14.184  INFO 5452 --- [127.0.0.1] jdbc.resultsettable  : 
|---------|
|?column? |
|---------|
|1        |
|---------|
```

Also you can output those SQL query and/or their result to a different log file. How to do this you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48985022/5380322).

Comment: That's great, but can you tell me instead of showing it on console how  can we add it in the file, also I don't want to specify the configuration in the application.properties, is there way to define these configuration in the logback-spring.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You could [turn on show_sql and log hibernate output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896998/log-file-to-track-jpa-hibernate-updates-insert-every-day) but it won't out of the box give you the data used in the changes, just the form of the sql. To get the data as well you'd need [to spy on the jdbc driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql).

You could use [spring data envers](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) to log changes to audit tables. Then from the tables you can export to files if you wish.

Or you could look at ways to [do the auditing at the db level](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin-log-settings/)

These are the options that come first to mind.